# uninitialized character array

Tags: c, mingw

I am getting the output "ma" on executing the following code. If my understanding is correct, local variable is not initialized to 0. So in such a case, how come %s is finding 0 in a1[2] itself? Is that we cannot predict the output in such cases and I am somehow getting this result and this may not be the case always?

```
int main(void)
{
    char a1[10];
    a1[0]='m';
    a1[1]='a';
    a1[3]='j';
    printf("%s",a1);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How is `a1` defined?

Comment: This is not the entire code. This gives `compilation error`. Show how `a1` is declared.

Comment: Please fix your question by adding the missing code.

Comment: updated the code with a1[]. Sorry, I just missed it while pasting to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **unless `a1` is `static`** <sup>note</sup>, being an automatic local variable, this is all *by-luck*. Your code (snippet) produces [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by missing the terminating `null`.

It just happens to have the immediate next byte as `null`, so it is printing *properly*. It is nowhere guaranteed that it will work very next time.

FWIW, `%s` format specifier expects a *string* and the definition of a *string* in C is a `null`-terminated `char` array. To copy the exact wordings,

> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type. [..] If the
>   precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall contain a null character.

---

Note: Related to the initialization of `static` variables, quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.9, Initialization, (*emphasis mine*)

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is **not initialized explicitly**, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration **is not initialized explicitly**, then:
>
> - [...]
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;

Comment: @juanchopanza Sir, tried to add some clarification. :)

Comment: There's a slight difference between the `static` keyword and the standard term static storage duration. For example: icky global variables have static storage duration even if they weren't declared as `static`. So the code formatting you've added, which is not there in the standard, is misleading.

Comment: @Lundin I did not get you sir. A local variable (as mentioned in the question) can have static storage duration only if `static` keyword is used. So, what did I miss there? And if the formatting is misleading, I'll remove that. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh The thing is, we don't know where that array is declared, because the question isn't clear and can't be answered... it could be declared at file scope, or at local scope, or as static. It could be uninitialized, or initialized, or partially initialized. In the worst case, it is not even an array but a pointer.

Comment: There still isn't enough information in the question to answer it meaningfully.